# Update Array Data In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have already done creating a form that can submit array data, however I am having problem on updating the array when user wants to edit the form data.

Here is in the view

```
@foreach($prescriptions as $prescription)

  <input type="hidden" name="prescript_id[]" value="{!! $prescription->prescript_id !!}"> 
    <tr> 
       <td><input class="form-control" name="drugname[]" type="text" value="{{ $prescription->drugname }}"></td>
       <td><input class="form-control" id="drugdosage" name="drugdosage[]" type="text" value="{{ $prescription->drugdosage }}"></td>
       <td><input class="form-control" id="frequency" name="frequency[]" type="text" value="{{ $prescription->frequency }}"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" id="notes" name="notes[]" type="text" value="{{ $prescription->notes }}"></td>
      <td>RM <input class="form-control" id="price" name="price[]" placeholder="0.00" type="text" value="{{ $prescription->price }}"></td>
      <td><a class="btn del">-</a></td>
 </tr>@endforeach
```

And here is in my controller on updating the data

```
public function update($consultid, Request $request)
{

        $docadvice = $request->get('docadvice');

        $drugnames = $request->get('drugname');
        $drugdosage = $request->get('drugdosage');
        $frequency = $request->get('frequency');
        $notes = $request->get('notes');
        $price = $request->get('price');

        $prescriptid = $request->get('prescript_id');

        $prescription = Prescription::where('prescript_id', '=', $prescriptid)->first();

            $count_items = count($drugnames);

        for($i = 0; $i<$count_items; $i++)
        {

            Prescription::where('prescript_id', '=', $prescriptid)->update([

            'drugname' => $drugnames[$i],
            'drugdosage' => $drugdosage[$i],
            'frequency' => $frequency[$i],
            'notes' => $notes[$i],
            'price' => $price[$i],
            'doc_advice' => $docadvice,

            ]);

        }

        return redirect(action('Doctor\PrescriptionController@edit', $consultation->consult_id))->with('status', 'The prescription has been updated!');
}
```

When I try to run the code, it is only takes the last values i have inserted not all values of rows updated (Assume there are two rows, when I inserted

row 1: Drug 1
row 2: Drug 2

Only Drug 2 will be updated on both rows.
row 1: Drug 2
row 2: Drug 2

Upon request I check on `dd($request->toArray());` all data inserted are read

Help me on how to update for both rows and for your information, I have created a dynamic table to add new row but it won't add the new row in database but only takes the last value to be updated for rows existed. Thank you.

This the table prescription 
[image]

I take out the hidden field and change to text
[image]

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="tblform table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>Drug Name</th>
                        <th>Drug Dosage</th>
                        <th>Frequency</th>
                        <th>Notes</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                   <tr>

                        <th>Drug Name</th>
                        <th>Drug Dosage</th>
                        <th>Frequency</th>
                        <th>Notes</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>

               @foreach($prescriptions as $prescription)

               <input type="text" name="prescript_id" value="{!! $prescription->prescript_id !!}"> 

              <tr> 
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" name="drugname[]" type="text" value="{{ $prescription->drugname }}">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input class="form-control" id="drugdosage" name="drugdosage[]" type="text" value="{{ $prescription->drugdosage }}">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input class="form-control" id="frequency" name="frequency[]" type="text" value="{{ $prescription->frequency }}">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input class="form-control" id="notes" name="notes[]" type="text" value="{{ $prescription->notes }}">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    RM <input class="form-control" id="price" name="price[]" placeholder="0.00" type="text" value="{{ $prescription->price }}">
                  </td>
                  <td><a class="btn del">-</a></td>
                </tr>
               @endforeach

                </tbody>
          </table>



<div class="btn-toolbar">
                       <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit">Save</button>
                       <button class="btn pull-right" type="reset">Reset</button>
                    </div>
              </div>

             <button type="button" class="add btn btn-info">Add New Row</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    </section>




 <table style="display:none" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="prototype">
  <tr> 
     <td>
      <input class="form-control" name="drugname[]" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" id="drugdosage" name="drugdosage[]" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" id="frequency" name="frequency[]" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" id="notes" name="notes[]" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
      RM <input class="form-control" id="price" name="price[]" placeholder="0.00" type="text">
    </td>
  <td><a class="btn del">-</a></td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: Can you please take a snapshot of the form wrap in view page source code, so I can see if you are having the prescription values or not in the hidden prescription field.

Comment: And why do you have taken that hidden field as an array?

Comment: @HaiderAli how to upload image here, im sorry, first time for questioning in here. Yes, the prescription values are there for every row. I take it as array so that when I add a new row, it would update new row and insert prescription values for new data. I guess... :(

Comment: but each prescription record should only have 1 id so I guess there is no need of making it an array

Comment: And there is an option for uploading image in the question editor

Comment: If you upload a snapshot of your page source i need to see the hidden in put field collects the prescription values or not. It looks like it is only having the last prescription id and that's why while editing it the last one is updated

Comment: And can you tell me little bit about your table fields like $prescription->drugdosage and $prescription->frequency are these strings separated by commas? or what?

Comment: Oh at the question editor.. I have edited it and uploaded some images on view and table prescription.

Comment: upload the image for view source code

Comment: @HaiderAli done that, and I change `prescript_id[ ]` to  `prescript_id` and now the the first value of the row is updated for both rows.

Comment: and what about before update? when you load this view, is it loading the correct prescription in each record or all are the same?

Comment: Make it an array again, looking at the view I got it you did that right. And please try the code I added and the answer

Comment: Before update the data, it loads the correct values for each rows, but when I edited the value and submit, it gets the first value and save to both rows.

Comment: which part you have added? @HaiderAli

Answer (score 1):

```
public function update($consultid, Request $request)
{
       $docadvice = $request->get('docadvice');
       $drugnames = $request->get('drugname');
       $drugdosage = $request->get('drugdosage');
       $frequency = $request->get('frequency');
       $notes = $request->get('notes');
       $price = $request->get('price');
       $prescriptid = $request->get('prescript_id');
       $count_items = count($drugnames);
       for($i = 0; $i<$count_items; $i++)
       {
            $prescription = Prescription::find($prescriptid[$i]);
            $prescription->update([
                'drugname' => $drugnames[$i],
                'drugdosage' => $drugdosage[$i],
                'frequency' => $frequency[$i],
                'notes' => $notes[$i],
                'price' => $price[$i],
                'doc_advice' => $docadvice,
            ]);
        }
        return redirect(action('Doctor\PrescriptionController@edit', $consultid))->with('status', 'The prescription has been updated!');
}
```

Comment: Error message appears Undefined variable: consultation at return redirect, and I changed that `$consultation->consult_id` to  `$prescription->consult_id` (because both carries the same value), magically it change someone else's prescription :(.

Comment: Change $consultation->consult_id to $consultid

Comment: If I do that, it shows another error FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function update() on null. It is highlighting on `$prescription->update([`

Comment: Do you have in Prescription model   protected $primaryKey = 'prescript_id'; ?

Comment: No, I just wrote `protected $guarded = ['id'];
      
    public function consultation()
   {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Consultation', 'consult_id');
   }`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
 public function update($consultid, Request $request) {

        $docadvice = $request->get('docadvice');

        $drugnames = $request->get('drugname');
        $drugdosage = $request->get('drugdosage');
        $frequency = $request->get('frequency');
        $notes = $request->get('notes');
        $price = $request->get('price');

        $prescriptid = $request->get('prescript_id');

        $prescription = Prescription::where('prescript_id', '=', $prescriptid)->first();

            $count_items = count($drugnames);

        for($i = 0; $i<$count_items; $i++)
        {

            $pres = Prescription::where('prescript_id', $prescriptid[$i])->first();

            $pres->update([
            'drugname' => $drugnames[$i],
            'drugdosage' => $drugdosage[$i],
            'frequency' => $frequency[$i],
            'notes' => $notes[$i],
            'price' => $price[$i],
            'doc_advice' => $docadvice,
            ]);

        }

        return redirect(action('Doctor\PrescriptionController@edit', $consultation->consult_id))->with('status', 'The prescription has been updated!'); }
```

Comment: Error message appears Undefined variable: consultation at return redirect.

Comment: Where is $consultation defined?

Answer (score 0):

as you can see `$prescriptid` is an array, so you must write it in a loop as you wrote the `$drugnames` like `$prescriptid[$i]``

Comment: I changed it to   `Prescription::where('prescript_id', '=', $prescriptid[$i])->update([
` but it keep updating the last value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$prescription = Prescription::findOrFail($prescriptid)->get();
$count_items = count($drugnames);

for($i = 0; $i<$count_items; $i++)
{
    $prescription[$count_items]->update([
        'drugname' => $drugnames[$i],
        'drugdosage' => $drugdosage[$i],
        'frequency' => $frequency[$i],
        'notes' => $notes[$i],
        'price' => $price[$i],
        'doc_advice' => $docadvice,
    ]);
}
```